# Undefined method, but I have clearly defined it?

Tags: ruby

I am a total beginner to Ruby and I'm trying to write a library which generates fake data. I'm getting a `NoMethodError` from one of my classes, but I have defined it, and I am not sure what is causing it.

Here are my classes:

**EntityFaker.rb**

```
=begin
    EntityFaker.rb
=end

require_relative "EntityFactory"

class Main

    public
    def self.generate_entities()
        puts "Generating entities..."
        EntityFactory.test_function()
    end

    generate_entities()
end
```

**EntityFactory.rb**

```
=begin
    Entity-Factory
=end

require 'faker'
require_relative 'Entities/Person'

class EntityFactory

    @@person_array = []

    public
    def self.test_function()
        generate_people(10)
    end

    private
    def self.generate_people(number)
        p = Person.new(age = number)
        puts p.to_string()
        # number.times do |n|
        #     p = Person.new(age = n)
        #     puts p.to_string()
        # end
    end
end
```

**Person.rb**

```
=begin
    Person.rb
=end

class Person

    def initialize(age = nil)
        @@age = age
    end

    public
    def self.to_string()
        return "#{@@age}"
    end
end
```

You can see I've clearly defined the `to_string()` method in the `Person` class, but when I run my code, I get the following error:

```
/home/user/Documents/entity-faker/EntityFactory.rb:20:in `generate_people': undefined method `to_string' for #<Person:0x0000564f481ddbc8> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/user/Documents/entity-faker/EntityFactory.rb:14:in `test_function'
    from EntityFaker.rb:12:in `generate_entities'
    from EntityFaker.rb:15:in `<class:Main>'
    from EntityFaker.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You `to_string` method is a class method, not an instance one. You should be able to do just `Person.to_string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the source code shared, you have defined to_string as a class method and then you are trying to access it with an instance of that class.

To use it as a class method, define

```
def self.to_string()
    return "#{@@age}"
end

Person.to_string()
```

To use it as a instance method, define

```
def to_string()
    return "#{@@age}"
end

Person.new.to_string()
```

Comment: Are the return statement, the empty parenthesis, and the class variable really needed?

Comment: the return statement is not necessary, empty parenthesis is not mandatory, I guess instance variable will be serve the same purpose as class variable in your case, the above code snippet has been taken from post to point out the error due to which it was arriving

Comment: Thank you for teaching me the difference between class and instance variables and thank you @SebastianPalma for pointing those extra parts out.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `self.` from your method names if you want instance methods. Check [Understanding self in Ruby](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-self-cheat-sheet/) for more details.

```
class Person

    def initialize(age = nil)
        @@age = age
    end

    public
    def to_string()
        return "#{@@age}"
    end
end

p = Person.new(13)
puts p.to_string() // 13
```

Also note that Ruby usually uses `.to_s` as the default to string method.